# Winter Bash 2016 is almost here - do we want to participate?

Tags: discussion

Like last year, I have an email from Stack Exchange, telling me that Winter Bash 2016 is ready, and **will start on 19 December**.

Because previous years have seen such a positive response, **the default position is "in"** - i.e. we *will* have hats.

If we don't want hats, we need to let the Stack Exchange team know by 13 December. Therefore, **on the 12th December**, I'll evaluate any responses to this post and let the team know our position.

If anyone has objections to hats, please post them as an answer here so the community can make its decision.

Answer (score 7):

Of course! *Everyone* loves hats.

[image: Richard Stallman as Saint iGNUcius]

<sup>[*Richard Stallman in his Saint iGNUcius Avatar*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RMS_iGNUcius_techfest_iitb.JPG) by Devashishsethia</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## HATS!

I want a Wobbuffet hat.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let's go for hats... whatever these are? What are they?

Comment: They're hats, for your avatar to wear. Keep its ears warm.

Comment: Oh me gosh they are HATS!!!! Hats hats hats!!! I just love hats!!!