# Featured question doesn't carry the featured tag?

Tags: bug, status-completed

[Winter Bash 2016 is almost here - do we want to participate?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/753/winter-bash-2016-is-almost-here-do-we-want-to-participate?cb=1) has been featured for quite a while now.

It's been nearly a month that it hasn't carried the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag. But for some reason, it keeps coming up as "Featured on Meta." It's been like that for a while, but even though it doesn't bother me, it's felt strange. It's also been locked since Dec 29th, so there wouldn't have been any activity on it to stir it up.

Comment: What's the betting it's because of the lock? I've unlocked it for a while, just to test it out

Comment: @ArtOfCode No clue. Maybe something happened when it was locked? I have no clue what could be up though. You see on the sidebar though, do you?

Comment: Yep. Give it an hour for the sidebar cache to expire, see if it's still there.

Comment: I'm not seeing it there now; is it fixed?

Comment: @MarcGravell Looks like it now! It seems like your presence is just magical! :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 well, I don't like to brag, but...

Comment: @MarcGravell Have you left? It's come back again.

Comment: I gave the cache a good kicking; let me know if the zombie starts to twitch and raises its head again: [I'm ready](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Ynq.jpg)

Comment: @MarcGravell Looks like you've scared the cache away. Let's see if it's only hiding behind a tree, watching us though.

Comment: @MarcGravell It looks like it's completely fixed. Should I put the [status-completed] tag up?